# How to use collection select for hidden value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-field

I have a table called sublet post which has these columns and there is a reference column to the property table.

```
  create_table "sublet_posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "property_id"
    t.index ["property_id"], name: "index_sublet_posts_on_property_id"
```

Property table

```
  create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "address"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

  end
```

In the sublet post form view

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= collection_select(:sublet_post, :property_id, @properties, :id, :address, prompt: true) %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :property_id, value: params[:sublet_post][:property_id]  %>
  </div>
```

In the form view, I am using the address as the selections and if a user clicks on an address, I would like the id to be stored in the for the value of the hidden value :property_id. I would like to do something similar to the code above.

Comment: Write a little javascript that handles the change event for the select. On change, get the id from the selected element and write it to the hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `id` to both elements and catch the `change` event.
The html will be so:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= collection_select(:sublet_post, :property_id, @properties, :id, :address, prompt: true, id: 'the_collection') %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :property_id, value: params[:sublet_post][:property_id], id: 'the_field'%>
</div>
```

And the javascript, if you are using `jQuery` :

```
$(document).on('change', '#the_collection', function(event) {
  var element = $(event.target);
  element.siblings('#the_field').val(element.val());
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/